# Is there a way to get a list of all Project from MS Project Online (PWA)

Tags: ms-project-server-2016

MS Project is a bucket of bolts... but sometimes we have to work with what we've got.

I have a MS Project online, Project Web Access (PWA) with no reporting capabilities like PowerBI or anything.

Is there any way to use VBA to get a list of all the projects in the online environment? PowerShell would be great, but I have no admin rights to use them. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/projectonline/export-user-data-from-project-online

Comment: After some research it would appear that since MS Project Online is a web based solution, one must use a web approach. 

So the answer lies somewhere in using REST apis: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119665/read-all-projects-within-project-online-using-web-part-sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

OData does the trick.

PowerBI and excel both have PowerQuery functionality with a OData connector, and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just use Project's native API:

URLPWA/_api/ProjectData/Projects